# expected initializer before ‘:’ token

Tags: c++

My code looks likes below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
     std::map<int, std::vector<int> > map;
     map[1].push_back(5);
     map[1].push_back(3);
     map[3].push_back(2);
     map[2].push_back(1);
     map[1].push_back(-1);
     map[3].push_back(2);

     int sum2 = 0;
     for (const pair<int, vector<int> >& index_vec : map) 
      {
        int sum = 0;
         for (int elem : index_vec.second) 
        { 
            sum += elem; 
        }
        sum2 += sum*sum;
         cout << "index " << index_vec.first << ": " << sum << endl;
      }
    cout << "sum_2: " << sum2 << endl; 
    return 0;
    };
```

Which works fine in my laptop but when using desktop gives me following erors:

```
map.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
map.cpp:17: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
map.cpp:29: error: expected primary-expression at end of input
map.cpp:29: error: expected ‘;’ at end of input
map.cpp:29: error: expected primary-expression at end of input
map.cpp:29: error: expected ‘)’ at end of input
map.cpp:29: error: expected statement at end of input
map.cpp:29: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

The output should be:

```
index 1: 7
index 2: 1
index 3: 4
sum_2: 66
```

which my laptop gives as expected. I have absolutely no idea, could soeone please help me out?

Comment: Maybe your desktop compiler does not support C++ 11.

Comment: You need to compile with `-std=c++11`

Comment: What is the solution then? I have to use my desktop.

Comment: Your code works on me.

Comment: @iBug however, no GNU specified. Just simply say use C++11 will be ok.

Comment: @iBug: so, if the file name is 'test.cpp' then how should I use your command? 'g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp' ? Not sure. Ellaborate please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works on me without any modification. Please check your compiler. You will need a C++11 compiler. If you use g++, something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 A.cpp
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11. You need at least 4.7. Please update your ancient compiler.

Comment: Still not working, says `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"`

Comment: @baban What compiler version are you using? Are you using an ancient compiler?

Comment: @baban Please report the compiler version.

Comment: I copied what you wrote 'g++ -std=c++11 A.cpp'. I am using `gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) `

Comment: @baban You will need at least 4.7.

Comment: @baban Your compiler is very old. Please update it. I think I've answered your question. Please consider to accept my answer with a tick.